# Does python have magic methods for all it's built-in functions?

Tags: python, built-in, magic-methods

Python supports a lot of magic methods for implementing custom functionality in objects, such as `__lt__`, `__getattr__`, etc. There are even magic methods that affect the way certain built-in functions perform, such as `__len__` and `__instancecheck__`. But are there magic methods for all the built-in functions in python?

For example, if I wanted to change the way the `any` function would perform on a certain class, could I specify an `__any__` magic method in that class? If that isn't an option, is there any way that I could specifically affect the way `any` applies to that class? (I realize that if I wanted special functionality for the way `any` receives the items from the iterable I could define `__iter__`, but that's not what I am looking to do)

Note that my desire to implement custom functionality for `any` is just an example, I don't explicitly want to define custom functionality for `any`.

Comment: No, there are plenty of built-in functions where hooking makes no sense. `chr()` for example, or `id()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, It makes a decent bit of sense for `chr`, if you were making your own number type you wanted to be used wherever an `int` can be used.

Comment: @MikeGraham Actually, that can be done by defining `__int__`, which is much more appropriate for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special method's let you hook into *concepts*, not so much built-in functions or other things.

`__len__` is a container length, not specifically a hook for the `len()` function. It just happens that the `len()` function is the visible API for that functionality.

`any()` expects an *iterable* argument, the concept you are looking for here is the [Iterator type methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter); it's not the function that is hooked, it is that concept.

You may want to study the [default type abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to see what methods Python types implement; here many special methods are grouped together in a readable overview.

Comment: "*`any()` expects an *iterator* argument" No, `any` expects an *iterable* argument.

Comment: @MikeGraham: indeed, `iter()` is called on it, so a iterable is enough. For some reason I still use the terms interchangeable but there is a difference that I should pay attention to more..

Answer (score 1):

No, only for lots of them, as practicality demands.

(Specifically for `__any__`, [it has been discussed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-March/052087.html) before, but ultimately, it wasn't considered to be needed.)

Answer (score 0):

No. The list of special methods a class can implement are [documented in section 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).